# Failing to filter the OK values from a vector of results in Rust

Tags: rust

I have been through a number of blogs / SOF posts and even the book. Unfortunately, I must be missing something very basic.

> Note: From the comments you all have made, I realize that my Q is
> incomplete.Apologies. I have added / edited as necessary.

Here's the code:

The user-defined type is `PerRequestData`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct PerRequestData {
    pub belongs_to_connection_idx: u16,
    pub what_happened_on_response: Result<TimeTakenForSuccessfulRequest, FailedRequestError>
}



let data_set: Vec<PerRequestData> =
    vec![
        PerRequestData::new(0, Ok(120)),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Err(FailedRequestError { time_taken_till_failure: 20, exact_reason_for_failure: AppErrorReason::TimeOut })),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Ok(120)),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Err(FailedRequestError { time_taken_till_failure: 20, exact_reason_for_failure: AppErrorReason::ResponseUnavailable })),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Ok(120)),

    ];

let p = data_set.iter().filter_map(Result::ok).collect();
```

I intend to filter out the `ok` values only, from that Vector, disregarding the `Err`s.

But the compiler disapproves of that last assignment to `p`.

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
   --> src/lib.rs:360:44
    |
360 |         let p = data_set.iter().filter_map(Result::ok).collect();
    |                                 ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^
    |                                 |          |
    |                                 |          expected due to this
    |                                 |          found signature defined here
    |                                 required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = note: expected function signature `fn(&PerRequestData) -> _`
               found function signature `fn(Result<_, _>) -> _`
note: required by a bound in `std::iter::Iterator::filter_map`
   --> /home/nirmalya/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:944:12
    |
944 |         F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> Option<B>,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `std::iter::Iterator::filter_map`
```

The compiler is trying to help me with what the main reason for its disapproval is, but somehow, I cannot understand why it is finding a function signature `fn(Result<_,_>) -> _` because all the types are available for it, to decide, aren't they?

This bothers me because I thought I had got the concept of Result<V,E> and its idiomatic processing, alright and clearly, I haven't.

Please nudge me to the right direction.

Update:

On being prodded by @kmdreko, @user3840170 and of course, @drewtato, I have got the code right (the changes I had to make made me feel a bit ashamed, I should have found the answer myself). Thanks!.

The playground link is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a2ed92ca895cccf6e8c7bba2370da58).

FWIW, I have used `flatten()` to get a `Vec<T>` from a `Vec<Result<T,E>>`, after ignoring the `E` in the result. This is in playground (commented).

Comment: Here's a nudge: you don't have a vector of results, you have a vector of `PerRequestData`.

Comment: `filter_map` expects a function taking a `&PerRequestData`. `Result::ok` takes a `Result`. `&PerRequestData` is not the same type as `Result`. Got it?

Comment: Agreed! It was a mistake on my part while copying the actual code to SOF, *not to use* the member variable for filtering. My intention is not to filter `PreRequestData` but `PerRequestData.what_happened_on_response`. I have added the `struct` definition to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your type includes a `Result`, you will either need to return them unchanged, or return some other type (such as what's inside the `Ok`).

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PerRequestData(i32, Result<i32, &'static str>);

impl PerRequestData {
    fn new(a: i32, b: Result<i32, &'static str>) -> Self {
        PerRequestData(a, b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data_set: Vec<PerRequestData> = vec![
        PerRequestData::new(0, Ok(120)),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Err("time out")),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Ok(120)),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Err("response unavailable")),
        PerRequestData::new(0, Ok(120)),
    ];

    // Find all `PerRequestData` with `Ok`
    let p: Vec<_> = data_set.iter().filter(|prd| prd.1.is_ok()).collect();
    dbg!(p);
    // Get all the `Ok` values
    let p: Vec<_> = data_set.iter().filter_map(|prd| prd.1.ok()).collect();
    dbg!(p);
}
```

I simplified the items since I don't know anything about your types. This may be different if your types are not `Copy`, but will depend on what you're after.

Comment: Your assumptions about the types were almost exact! ;-) My code is in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a2ed92ca895cccf6e8c7bba2370da58